# Redirect compilation mode hyperlink to external tool

Tags: overlays, compilation-mode, hyperlinks

I have a working compilation error matcher, that contains the path to a file. The compilation buffer correctly adds a hyperlink to that file and I can open it in emacs. However, the file in question is an html report which I would like to open using an external browser. I already know how to modify the file element, so I could change it to give emacs a hint to open it with system tools. I think of something similar to a trump prefix for `find-file`, but in this case for overlay hyperlinks. Does such a prefix exist?

As a bonus question: I would like to not use the system default browser but a specific one, say firefox. How could that be done?

Note: I think as a last resort to try something like `openwith`, but this would smell more like a hack, because in general I want to open end edit html file in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine `next-error-function` in the compilation buffer and make it do something else, while using `compilation-next-error-function` as a fall-back.  It's probably going to be some work.

Comment: In that case I would rather not let compilation-mode search for those errors and go for a `(add-to-list 'compilation-finish-functions #'my-highlight-and-make-external-tool-buttons)` or a hook like `compilation-filter-hook`. In my use case the files with external link are all at the buffer bottom, so I do not need `compilation-next-error`. I have to explore that in more detail, maybe someone can give me a hint which hook could be appropriate for this? Anyway, for completenes: how could I weave my findings into a `compilation-next-error`  in custom filter functions?